# cat > $FILE_NAME << EOF - Explanation of the inner workings

Tags: redirection, cat, eof

I know what this one does, I learned "pattern like" and just works.

I also know:

- that `>` is a redirect to a file
- that `<<` <s>is also a redirect to file</s> see below
- `EOF` is just a placeholder, when detected the file is closed

Can someone explain the *inner workings* of those instructions? Why does that work ?

**Correction:** the use of ´<<` is described in the man page of bash as:

```
<<[-]word
    here-document
delimiter
```

So it is the current source that is read from, which I think is stdin. Could someone decompose this into smaller chunks, that I can understand?

I think delimiter corresponds to `EOF` in my example, right?

And here-document is probably the text I type in in stdin, right?

I fail to see what is word.

Comment: `<<` is _not_ a redirect from a file.  `<<EOF` signifies the start of a _here document_.  Open `man bash` and go to the section entitled "Here Documents."

Comment: There are many, *many* references on how to use the shell on the Internet (and some of them are clear and accurate).  Start by reading *the very next paragraph* of `bash(1)` after the block you quoted; also check [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/23408) (here on Stack Exchange).  Please do some research on your own, and let us know if something specific is hard to understand.

Comment: Your link is perfect. The use of two different identifiers "word" and "delimiter" was confusing, they are actually the same. Thanks.